# FAILED => unsupported connection type: winrm

Tags: windows, ansible

I'm trying to follow instruction on this site:
http://docs.ansible.com/intro_windows.html
to control windows machine using ansible.

But unfortunately when I run this command:

```
ansible windows -i myinventory -m win_ping --ask-vault-pass
```

I get this kind of error:

```
windows.machine.com | FAILED => unsupported connection type: winrm
```

On the linux control machine I've installed pywinrm and on the windows machine there is PowerShell version 4.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest ansible. Probably you will have to install pywinrm too

```
sudo pip install pywinrm
```